# OSB - Get endpoint from business services to log this endpoint

Tags: osb

How can i get in a proxy flow the business service endpoint?. I want to log this endpoint in my log file.
I use OSB 11.1.1.7.

Thanks

Comment: Could you be more specific? How can we help, what did you try and were did you run into problems?

Comment: I need to get it with "log action" or "report action" the endpoint value of a business service, that it is configured in a routing action of a proxy Message flow.

Answer (score 2):

Try with $outbound/ctx:transport/ctx:uri from proxy.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved with use of "Message Tracing" functionality. Look under "Operational Settings" tab. Make sure to set the detail level to "Full".

Unfortunately there is no OOTB functionality to access service endpoint value  inside OSB pipeline. Context variable $outbound/ctx:transport/ctx:uri mentioned before is only used to override default endpoint URI. ctx:uri is never initialized on the outbound variable. This information can be found in chapter "39.4.1.2 transport" of "Fusion Middleware Administrator's Guide for Oracle Service Bus"(https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/admin.1111/e15867/context.htm#OSBAG326) .